# How to Open CS-Cart inside an iframe

Tags: iframe, cs-cart

I am wondering if anyone can help me here.

I am trying to open CS-Cart inside an iframe, but it will not work- once i remove the iframe, then it loads.

There is nothing wrong with the iframe as i tried other carts like Magento etc and they work but its only CS-Cart which doesn't.

Here is the link to the preview, where i want the CS-cart demo to open http://www.shopping-cart-hub.com/items/preview/22

if you guys need the links i can post it here to explain- i am new here so not sure if i can.

Thanks

Comment: Please either include the links to the affected page or the relevant code.

Comment: hello- thanks for replying- if you remove the frame from the top left of that link page above- you will get the affected page- and for that matter you can take even the official demo of cs-cart [link](http://demo.cs-cart.com/professional/?sl=EN) - even that will not work inside an iframe.